# Laravel passing unrelated data to the register view

Tags: php, laravel

I need to pass data from an unrelated model into the register view using the built in auth. What is the cleanest way of achieving this?

This is what's in the Auth controller:

```php
public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->registrar = $registrar;

    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}
```

Comment: Its really not, if you look at laravels built in auth it would make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is much easier than I anticipated. To pass data to the register view you simply need to override the `getRegister` method in your `AuthController` and pass the data to the view:

```php
public function getRegister()
{
    $products = \App\Product::all();
    $data = [
        'products' => $products
    ];

    return view('auth.register')->with($data);
}
```

Comment: In Laravel 5.3 it is called `showRegistrationForm`.

Answer (score 8):

Here I get the solution when I am face similar problem with you.

**First step**

You find the action route of laravel registration post. Just type "**php artisan route:list**"

if yo're using **Laravel 5.3**, it can be found at **showRegistrationForm** Method.

**Second Step.**

Add new method as overridding of **showRegistrationForm** method in RegisterController.php

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    $product = Product::all();
    return view("auth.register", compact("product"));
}
```

in the older version, it using getRegister method to overriding the action.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @susilogn ! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.7 you only have to override the method `showRegistrationForm()` found on *vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth*

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    //Custom code here
    return view('auth.register');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a controller that loads your registration view? If you want to pass data to it simply use "with" `return view('path.to.registration.view')->withData($someDateFromAnyModel)`

In this case you will now have access to a "$data" variable in your registration view that equals $someDateFromAnyModel.

Comment: As this is the built in auth there is no return view.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? You should be able to make modifications to the provided AuthController.

Comment: 5, i'm not clear how to go about this as it's not doing a make view as I'm normally use to doing

Comment: I see what you mean. Well I can think of 3 options. 1. just create your own AuthController. This will give you the most flexibility. 2. If you want to use the built in AuthController, then you can use blade service injection to inject some date into your registration view. You can learn more here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#service-injection. 3. You can use view composers.

Comment: Thank you, you are so much more helpful than @bogdan.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.